# How to execute function after loading the view

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am using `Codeigniter` and I have two functions in my controller. The Problem is that my view file is loading very slow. When I figure it out I came to know that in my function there is an function call before loading view page e.g

```
$this->_review_and_give_point_for_alert($alertDetail, $alertID, $alertUserId, $email, $alert_url, $statusImage, $userStatus);
```

This is causing to load view page slow. View file is just a 'thankyou' message.

I am not getting any data through this function which is supposed to be show on view file. Infact it is updating data in database. So the question is how I can load my view file i.e thank you message quickly. Any **help** would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have two function in the controller.

```
function loadPage(){
```

and

```
function showSuccesful(){
```

the `loadPage()` for show view to customer that is very slow.
in your viewfile.html you can have `Ajax function` for call `showSuccesful` in controller to say The page Loaded!! successfully.

you can call `Ajax function` in `$(document).ready()` in script tag.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

@Hamed, wouldn't that beat the purpose of presenting the view after updating the record?

What if the update fails for some reason?

He can 'insert' the data in a temporary table (quicker than a full update), present the user with the 'Thank You' view and batch update the master-table later in the day at a time interval of his choice, ie, every 6 hours, like a scheduled script and while each record gets updated in the 'master-table', the record from the temporary table gets deleted.

All this happens in the background without delaying the user experience.

1. $this->_save_in_temp_table($alertDetail, $alertID, $alertUserId, $email, $alert_url, $statusImage, $userStatus);
2. Present "Thank You" view to user.
3. Run scheduler automatically/manually to update the data in (1) above. Delete the data from the "Temp Table" upon successful update.
4. This way, the user does not have wait for long because inserts are faster than updates.

Comment: hammid logic will work because thankyou view file is not supposed to be load unless untill everything above work fine

Comment: You are going by the assumption that 1) Update will happen regardless so let me load the 'success' page anyway. You load the 'success' part and try to update the row in an Ajax call. That is a smart approach but what if the Ajax call fails and the client is still presented with a "success" page with the assumption that all went well. When you look into your database later, you find unpredictable anomalies.